# How to transform a legacy widget into a block

Tags: javascript, widgets, block-editor, rest-api

WP 5.8 (not released yet) will include support for transforming legacy widgets into blocks. I have a custom legacy widget I'm trying to add support for transforming it into a block. Reading the docs I added the following code to one of my blocks. My legacy widget had two attributes (`attribute1` and `attribute2`):

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
transforms: {
    from: [
        {
            type: 'block',
            blocks: [ 'my/custom-block' ],
            isMatch: ( { idBase, instance } ) => {
                if ( ! instance?.raw ) {
                    // Can't transform if raw instance is not shown in REST API.
                    return false;
                }
                return idBase === 'my-custom-widget';
            },
            transform: ( { instance } ) => {
                const transformedBlock = createBlock(
                    'my/custom-block',
                    {
                        attribute1: instance.raw.attribute1,
                        attribute2: instance.raw.attribute2,
                    }
                );
                if ( ! instance.raw?.title ) {
                    return transformedBlock;
                }
                return [
                    createBlock( 'core/heading', {
                        content: instance.raw.title,
                    } ),
                    transformedBlock,
                ];
            },
        },
    ]
},
```

**PHP:**

This is the `__construct()` function in my legacy widget. I added the `show_instance_in_rest` arg so the widget can be seen in the REST API:

```
function __construct() {
    $widget_ops = array(
        'classname'             => 'my-custom-widget',
        'show_instance_in_rest' => true
    );
    parent::__construct( 'my-custom-widget', 'My Custom Widget', $widget_ops );
}
```

But when I click the Transform button in the new widget editor in WP 5.8 beta2, there is no option to transform it into my custom block, just into the Columns and Group blocks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that at the time this question was asked, the block based widget editor has yet to be finalised and is due to be included in the as yet unreleased WordPress 5.8.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying the beta2 at the moment.

Comment: Hello, I'm not familiar with block editor at all. Trying to [migrate legacy widget to a block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/widgets/legacy-widget-block/) but stuck at #2 (Add block transform). I don't know how or where to add those `transform:{..}` code. Do you know any example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I'm answering my question:

The `blocks` parameter in the transform code should be `[ 'core/legacy-widget' ]` instead of `[ 'my/custom-block' ]`. For a `from` transform it indicates the block(s) you want to transform from, which in this case is a legacy widget.

Comment: i have a question for you, where to put javascript file... what to name it? etc... the docs mention block's definition ... where is that? can you help please?